# Chrome Dev Tool: Length of Tab Indent When Copying

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Something recently changed on my Chrome Dev Tool, but I'm not sure what it was. Generally, after debugging in Chrome, I copy my updated code and paste it into Notepad++. Recently the indention changed from 4 spaces to 2. At first I thought, "I'll just change the indention length in Notepad++", but then it makes my HTML harder to read.

I messed with the tab indent options in the Dev Tool settings, but it didn't fix my issue. I tried both "Detect Indention" On & Off and different spacings for "Default Indention". Please help!

[image]